# How do I extraxt audio files from mkv files? TO DELET THE MUSIC IN THE BACKGROUND

Tags: sound, extract, mkv

I want to know how to get all the audio files from the mkv file.
it has to be more than one file.
SO I CAN DELETE *THE MUSIC IN THE BACKGROUND* of THE VIDEO.

1. What software I can use?
2. And how to use it?
   3- And if i need video editor what is it?

and don't tell me to use noise reduction in Audacity
IT'S SO BAD.

But this have to work for ubuntu 18.04.

(If you don't understand me I'm sorry, Because I'm not a native speaker)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it's very easy to extract audio files from *.mkv files. I suggest you to install MKVToolNix, from here > https://mkvtoolnix.download/ and follow but I'll outline what you have to do:

- open your terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>)
- run this commands:

  ```
  wget -q -O - https://mkvtoolnix.download/gpg-pub-moritzbunkus.txt | sudo apt-key add -
  sudo apt update
  sudo apt install mkvtoolnix mkvtoolnix-gui
  ```
- after that you can open with right click you mkv files and untick all except audio files. After that you can save your mpa (MP4 audio only) file(s) somewhere.

Here, I've compiled video to help you :)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

ffmpeg is a really useful and versatile tool for this type of task. See a good explanation here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27413824/6859929

Or summarized:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
ffmpeg -i input-video.mkv -vn -acodec copy output-audio.opus
```

**EDIT 2018-12-20**: The OP was about extracting the audio track from an MKV container. Actually modifying the track needs very different tools, and Audacity is probably quite appropriate. However, removing (white) noise probably won't have any positive effect, since background music isn't that type of noise.

If the music is stronger in some frequencies you can try and band-pass filter the signal to dampen those frequencies.

If you have the audio track of the signal you want to remove, you can try and subtract it from the original signal - possibly after Fourier transforming both of them.