# How to extract video, audio and subtitles files from an MKV file

Tags: sound, video, subtitle, mkv

I have some MKV video files and I want to extract (not convert) the internal files (video, audio and subtitles).

I thought MKVToolNix GUI was the appropiate app to do that, but... I cannot to find any button to perform the action!

Of course, MKVToolNix GUI shows me the individual files, but... The only option I get is to save it as MKV file, again!

So...

I thought WinFF could help me, but... I cannot to choice from the internal files in the MKV container, so... I just get the main video and audio files, together, and not subtitles.

So...

I thought some compressed files extractor could help, but... Not at all!

So...

Is there some another way, or app, to get this?

I insist I don't want to convert anything, not. I just want to get the separated files (video, audio and subtitles) to use it in this separated way.

Comment: Those are three different questions :P And all three are likely to have been asked before.

Comment: Audio:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/432122/how-to-extract-audio-from-video-not-converting-video-into-audio-file   https://askubuntu.com/questions/1102707/how-do-i-extraxt-audio-files-from-mkv-files-to-delet-the-music-in-the-backgroun

Comment: subtitles https://askubuntu.com/questions/452268/extract-subtitle-from-mkv-files

Comment: Nice answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32922226/7358809

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your ideas! But... I think I didn't use the right words to my question: MKV file is an original HDD FOLDER (with video, audio and subtitles independent internal files) converted into just one file (MKV CONTAINER). My question is: How can I reconvert the MKV file into the original FOLDER (with the all internal independent files as video, audio and subtitles original files)? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

this will extract out the audio from a mkv file

```
ffmpeg -i /tmp/dolbycanyon.m4v -vn -acodec copy /tmp/dolbycanyon.aac
```

prior to running above you could show details of the input video file

```
ffprobe  /tmp/dolbycanyon.m4v 

# ... output

Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/tmp/dolbycanyon.m4v':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : M4V 
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1
    encoder         : Lavf57.66.105
  Duration: 00:00:38.07, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 663 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x480 [SAR 8:9 DAR 4:3], 313 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 341 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

resultant output audio details are shown here

```
ffprobe  /tmp/dolbycanyon.aac 

ffprobe version 4.2.1-2ubuntu1 Copyright (c) 2007-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.2.1-21ubuntu1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=2ubuntu1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
[aac @ 0x563336f5cc40] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, aac, from '/home/pie/Downloads/dolbycanyon.aac':
  Duration: 00:00:41.70, bitrate: 313 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 313 kb/s
```